# Android volley is not calling getParams() after second intent

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a code to login/register/update users using volley the main issue is the second attempt to send parameters it doesn't and sends the first parameters again

example: I send "abc" and on the second attempt I send "xyz" but the volley sends "abc" instead of "xyz"

This is the code i have:

```
/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password ,final String fbid) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Iniciando Sesión ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_UPDATEFB, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "UPDATE Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in


                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.upUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FaceActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Log.e(TAG, "datos enviados: " + email + password);
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("fbid", fbid);
            Log.e(TAG, "paramis:" + params);
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

This is my app controller

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

}

My logcats 1st attempt:

```
    01-19 16:56:07.084 30294-31077/com.dattasolutions.imageupload E/RegisterActivity: paramis:{fbid=10155452149683353, email=demo, password=1q2w3e}
01-19 16:56:07.084 30294-31077/com.dattasolutions.imageupload I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
01-19 16:56:07.084 30294-31077/com.dattasolutions.imageupload I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
01-19 16:56:07.084 30294-31077/com.dattasolutions.imageupload I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 39 with tag bd9bffbf00000000{3181117375,0} uid -1, pid: 30294, getuid(): 10362
01-19 16:56:07.114 30294-30294/com.dattasolutions.imageupload D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
01-19 16:56:08.924 30294-31077/com.dattasolutions.imageupload I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 39
01-19 16:56:08.974 30294-30294/com.dattasolutions.imageupload D/RegisterActivity: UPDATE Response: {"error":true,"error_msg":"User already existed with demo"}
```

second attempt i used "demos" instead of "demo":

```
    01-19 16:56:25.904 30294-30294/com.dattasolutions.imageupload D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
01-19 16:56:26.724 30294-30294/com.dattasolutions.imageupload D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-19 16:56:26.784 30294-30294/com.dattasolutions.imageupload D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-19 16:56:26.784 30294-30294/com.dattasolutions.imageupload D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3ad9968 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-1002,348}
01-19 16:56:26.834 30294-30294/com.dattasolutions.imageupload D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
01-19 16:56:26.834 30294-30294/com.dattasolutions.imageupload D/RegisterActivity: UPDATE Response: {"error":true,"error_msg":"User already existed with demo"}
```

If you see

```
01-19 16:56:07.084 30294-31077/com.dattasolutions.imageupload E/RegisterActivity: paramis:{fbid=10155452149683353, email=demo, password=1q2w3e}
```

not showing on the second logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because volley params cache.
I cleaned the cache with command:
 `getCache().clear();`

And added these lines after

```
// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
//we clean the cache
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.getCache().clear();
requestQueue.add(strReq);
```